# icCube - JavaScript expression cell background color

Tags: javascript, iccube-reporting

In the cell renderer → Cell background color → Expression of my table, I simply want to put some JavaScript to fill my Cell background depending on the value.

I'm getting this error :

```
"Missing value for parameter: Document"
```

My script :

```js
function(context, ...args) {
  if (context.getValue(row) > 0.5) {
    return "#000";
  } else {
    return "#fff";
  }
}
```

Comment: We tried an it looks ok to us

Comment: ok, seems that context.getValue(row); is wrong
context.getValue(); works